# How can I shorten an algorithm that employs different scenarios with similar code?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have developed a program that solves kinematic equations in elementary physics. To solve, one needs 3 out of a possible 5 variables. There are 10 different combinations of what 3 variables are known. I coded 10 scenarios similar to the two blocks of code below

```
    // If we have acceleration, final velocity, and initial velocity
    if (varEntered[0] == true && varEntered[1] == true && varEntered[2] == true)
    {
        double acceleration = knownVariables[0];        //Setting acceleration
        double finalVelocity = knownVariables[1];       //Setting finalVelocity
        double initVelocity = knownVariables[2];        //Setting initVelocity

        double time = ((finalVelocity - initVelocity)/acceleration);        //Finding time using an equation
        double distance = ((finalVelocity + initVelocity)*((0.5)*time));    //Finding distance using an equation

        System.out.println("The time is " + time + " seconds");             //Printing time
        System.out.println("The distance is " + distance + " meters");      //Printing distance
    }




    //If we have distance, final velocity, initial velocity
    if (varEntered[3] == true && varEntered[1] == true && varEntered[2] == true)
    {
        //Known variables
        double distance = knownVariables[3];        //Acceleration
        double finalVelocity = knownVariables[1];   //Final Velocity
        double initVelocity = knownVariables[2];    //Initial Velocity

        // Unknown variables
        double time = (distance/((0.5)*(finalVelocity + initVelocity)));    //Time
        double acceleration = ((finalVelocity - initVelocity)/time);        //Acceleration

        System.out.println("The time is " + time + " meters/second");                               //Printing time
        System.out.println("The acceleration is " + acceleration + " meters/second^2");     //Printing distance
    }
```

These seem very similar, but are different scenarios. As a programming beginner, I am wondering if the algorithm I use can be modified to shorten the code. If any more info is needed I will be more than happy to provide.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a function that accepts three numbers and performs the general calculation.
For a starter, try [this tutorial](http://xahlee.info/java-a-day/writing_a_func.html). Then you can call your function twice, each time with different sets of variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Map and do something like this (warning: pseudocode):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

 Map<String,double> map=new HashMap<String, double>();
```

Initialize the map with all the values that are known, e.g.:

```
 map.put("initVelocity", 0.35);
```

Then you can define the following function:

```
void  calculateValues(Map<double,String> map){

if( map.containsKey("initVelocity") && map.containsKey("finalVelocity") && map.containsKey("acceleration")){
map.put("time",((map.get("finalVelocity") - map.get("initVelocity")/map.get("acceleration"));    
}

add all the other algorithms here in the same way!!!

}
```

This function takes the values that are already defined in the HashMap and tries to calculate the missing parameters. It will often be necessary to call it multiple times on a map until all parameters are set. You could do something like:

```
while( the map has not all values set){
calculateValues(map);
}
```

Also, you could make sure (by adding this condition to  the if-statements) that any of the algorithms is called only if the resulting values are not set yet. But don't worry too much about that.

Answer (score 0):

From what I noticed, it seems each variable is associated with a number. You can eliminate all the possible scenarios completely and have if conditions on each of the five variables; through this identify the 3 variables first and initialize the local variables. They are independent of each other when assigned, so there's no reason to make that many combinations. This will shorten the code by a lot.

The next step is to shorten the number of combinations you have. The best thing I can think of is finding out the two values you need to compute and using the formulas, in other words another block of if else statements. Here's what the code would look like:

```
//initialize all to 0
double acceleration = 0;
double distance = 0;        
double finalVelocity = 0;
double initVelocity = 0;
double time = 0;

//place the proper values for each 
if (varEntered[0] == true){
    acceleration = knownVariables[0];
}
if (varEntered[1] == true){
    finalVelocity = knownVariables[1];
}
if (varEntered[2] == true){
    initVelocity = knownVariables[2];
}
if (varEntered[3] == true){
    distance = knownVariables[3];
}
if (varEntered[4] == true){
   time = knownVariables[4];
}

// now you have 10 cases 
if(varEntered[0] == false && varEntered[1] == false){
//use the formulas here
} else if (varEntered[0] == false && varEntered[2] == false){
//use other formula here
}// repeat for the next 8, with each time you change the condition and formulas 
//like you have it. Also, I noticed that you missed the else in your conditionals; 
//it is more efficient if you use if-else clauses when only one should execute every time you run the code.
```

Hope this helps.

Feel free to copy this out, fill the rest and try it out.

Comment: I like your approach. This does shorten the code significantly, yet include all the combinations. Also thanks for your observation about using "if...else if...else" statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you're careful with your dependencies, you can get away with 5 cases with 1 calculation each instead of 10 cases with 2 calculations each.  To do this, you have to make sure that no two variables directly depend on each other.  If that were to happen, then you would be out of luck when both of the variables are unknown.

One way to do this is to take your list of variables and calculate each variable in terms of the following three (wrapping around when you reach the end of the list), as in the following example.  In this example, solveAll takes an array of doubles with the unknowns set to Double.MAX_VALUE, and it sets the unknowns to the correct values.  (If there are more than two unknowns, you'll get an infinite recursion.)

```
// Really should use enum instead of constant ints, and an EnumMap instead of an array.
public final static int ACCELERATION = 0;
public final static int FINALVELOCITY = 1;
public final static int INITVELOCITY = 2;
public final static int DISTANCE = 3;
public final static int TIME = 4;

private double[] vars;

public void solveAll(double[] vars) {
    this.vars = vars;
    for (int i=ACCELERATION; i<=TIME; i++) {
        get(i);
    }
}

private double get(int v) {
    if (vars[v] != Double.MAX_VALUE) {
        return vars[v];
    }

    switch (v) {
    case ACCELERATION:
        return (vars[ACCELERATION] = (get(FINALVELOCITY)*get(FINALVELOCITY) - get(INITVELOCITY)*get(INITVELOCITY)) / (2*get(DISTANCE)));
    case FINALVELOCITY:
        return (vars[FINALVELOCITY] = 2*get(DISTANCE)/get(TIME) - get(INITVELOCITY));
    case INITVELOCITY:
        return (vars[INITVELOCITY] = get(DISTANCE)/get(TIME) - get(ACCELERATION)*get(TIME)/2);
    case DISTANCE:
        return (vars[DISTANCE] = (get(FINALVELOCITY) - get(ACCELERATION)*get(TIME)/2) * get(TIME));
    case TIME:
        return (vars[TIME] = (get(FINALVELOCITY) - get(INITVELOCITY)) / get(ACCELERATION));
    }

    return Double.MAX_VALUE; // Bad variable index
}
```